# Error in Inner Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to practice inner joins but in vain.I am getting table does not exist error while executing inner join statements even though I have created tables and data are present

Kindly help me with this.Also, it shows Customers is disconnected from rest of the join graph.

I have tried using double quotes for table names but then it gives different error as

> ORA-00904: "CUSTOMERS"."CUSTOMER_ID": invalid identifier 
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

```
SELECT
    Orders.OrderID,
    Customers.CustomerName
FROM
    Orders
    inner join Customers on Orders.Customer_Id = Customers.Customer_Id;
```

Its `Oracle 11g` and `SYS` is the owner.

Comment: The error message says that `Customer_Id` is an invalid identifier. Are you sure that's what the column is named? I see your other column is named `OrderID` (without an underscore) so maybe it's `CustomerID` instead?

Comment: Is there a column in table `Customers` called `Customer_Id`

Comment: You'd rather stop doing what you're doing now. Create another user for testing purposes, leave SYS alone.

Comment: My two tables are as follows Create table "Customers"(
Customer_Id Number(25),
CustomerName varchar2(35),
Address varchar2(30),
City varchar2(25));

Comment: Create table "Orders"(
Customer_Id Number(25),
OrderID Number(10),
EmployeeID Number(10),
OrderDate Date);

Comment: **NEVER**, ***ever*** create your own tables in the SYS or SYSTEM account. Create a regular user to do that. Do **NOT** use the SYS account for your regular work. Just don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be due to your `create table` statement,which contains double quoted table names, that are **not** all in uppercase. Remember, oracle always stores table names and column names in uppercase by default, unless you have used double quoted strings with varying case in the `create/Alter` statements.Using the whole table names to refer the columns should be avoided, as that is the reason for `invalid identifier` error in your case.

So, either **rename** the table from `"Customers"` to `CUSTOMERS` and `"Orders"` to `ORDERS` if you can, or use quotes for table names in your select query along with appropriate aliases .

```
SELECT
    o.OrderID,
    c.CustomerName
FROM
    "Orders" o
    inner join "Customers" c on o.Customer_Id = c.Customer_Id;
```

Also, as @horse has already suggested, create table in any sample schema like HR, SCOTT etc and not in `SYS`.

Comment: I renamed the tables to CUSTOMERS  and ORDERS and iam able to perform all joins successfully..Many thanks for the help